# Create dynamic columns with Primeng but the first column should be static

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the new `<p-table>` of Primeng and I would like to set the first column static and generate the following columns dynamically.

In the first column I would set buttons for different actions for each row but I have no idea how to define the first column as static one.

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <!--
             <th>
               Action
             </th>
            -->
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <!--
             <td>
               <button>...
             </td>
            -->
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: You're doing right. Just remove comments and close your `button` tag. Then it should be ok, no ?

Comment: It is !!!! Hahaha